# My Picture box is not giving the output of an image

Tags: vb.net

Help my code is not running but its catching my error message, I want to show the images from my database and i will pass it to my picture box

'This is my code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtsearch.Click
        Try
            disconnect()
            connect()
            cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("Select * FROM tblemployee WHERE lname ='" & Trim(TextBox1.Text.TrimEnd()) & "'", con)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

            If dr.Read() Then

                PictureBox1.Image = (dr("emp_pix"))
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("No Information Record, Please Name!")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Please try again" & ex.Message)

        End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your exception message?

Comment: when I am inputing an invalid data from my database it gives me No info record, Please Name!....  And if it is correct it will not give a message and it will do nothing. not loading the image.

Comment: What is the datatype of emp_pix???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't display directly byte as Image. you need to convert it and display it.

Try like this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtsearch.Click
        Try
            disconnect()
            connect()
            cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("Select * FROM tblemployee WHERE lname ='" & Trim(TextBox1.Text.TrimEnd()) & "'", con)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

            If dr.Read() Then
                Dim bytBLOBData() As Byte = dr("emp_pix")
                Dim stmBLOBData As New MemoryStream(bytBLOBData)
                PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stmBLOBData)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("No Information Record, Please Name!")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Please try again" & ex.Message)

        End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Just hopefully he is storing it correctly, or there will be another issue . . .